# ErrorPageFilter conflicting with ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

As I want to control the output from all endpoints of my application including for endpoints not explicitly defined, I created a simple `DefaultController` looking like this.

```
@RestController
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public void unmappedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

I also have a `@ControllerAdvice` error controller that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and overrides all methods from that class, and specifically

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    if(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(status)) {
        request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception", ex, 0);
    }

    SearchOutput output = new SearchOutput(body);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(output, headers, status);
}
```

I also added a method to handle the `ResourceNotFoundException` thrown by the default mapper.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;

    ErrorOutput out = new ErrorOutput("Resource not found", status);
    return this.handleExceptionInternal(ex, out, headers, status, request);
}
```

I declared `error.whitelabel.enabled:false` and added `exclude={ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class}` to the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation, and still have two problems when running this application in a standalone Tomcat container:

- `ErrorPageFilter` complains about the fact that it `Cannot forward to error page for request [/something/not/existing] as the response has already been committed` every time the `ResourceNotFoundException` is thrown;
- when the browser (automatically) requests `favicon.ico`, a `Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method` error for the `handleExceptionInternal` method is logged, with description `Could not find acceptable representation`.

Also - is this an acceptable way to deal with non-existing resources?

Comment: The easiest way to handle this situation is to just define error page mappings and have an error controller (I prefer to map based on HTTP codes - easier to map 404 codes rather than specific exceptions being thrown) - this link shows you how to define error page mappings in Spring Boot http://www.sporcic.org/2014/05/custom-error-pages-with-spring-boot/.